# using paypal express checkout API to handle payments for third parties?

Tags: paypal

i am creating a small marketplace where sellers can sell their products and receive payments to their PayPal account directly from the buyer.

i've previously been using "website payments standard" but am looking to switch to the express checkout API to generate a one-time payment token each time someone purchases something and which then allows buyer@email.com to send a payment directly to seller@email.com without the involvement of my PayPal account.

is that possible?

i've only found one option in the documentation at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/ called "PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID", but is that the correct way to send the entire payment from the buyer to the seller without any amount going to me?

also, do i NEED to have my own "USER" and "PWD" to generate an API token each time if I am receiving no payment mysefl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you are looking for [Adaptive payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/).

`Adaptive payments handles payments between a sender of a payment and one or more receivers of the payment. You are an application owner, such as a merchant that owns a website, the owner of a widget on a social networking site, the provider of a payment application on mobile phones, and so on. Your application is the caller of Adaptive Payments API operations.`

So, in general if you want to act as API caller and to felicitate the money transfer between buyer and seller, Adaptive payment is the way to go.

[Steps to go live with Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/)